# How do I access the value of a td (x3) of the same tr (x1), if I click on the tr (x1 of td (x2))?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, tr

How do I access the value of a td (x3) of the same tr (x1), if I click on the tr (x1 of td (x2))?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/Usuario/GetPermisosRolPorUsuario',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType:'JSON',
        data: { NitEmpresa,NombreUsuario },
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer '
                + sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken")
        },
        success: function (data) {
            debugger
            $('#tblBody').empty();
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                var row =
                    $('<tr>'
                        +'<td id="IdUsuario">'+ value.IdUsuario + '</td>'
                        + '<td id="RolId">'   + value.RolId     + '</td>'
                        + '<td id="Estado" >' + value.Estado + '</td>'
                        + '<td>' + value.Rol + '</td>'
                        + '<td>' + value.DescripcionRol + '</td>'
                        + '<td>' + value.NombreUsuario + '</td>'
                        + '<td>' + value.FullName + '</td>'
                        + '<td>' + value.licenciaEmpresa + '</td>'
                        + '<td>' + value.RazonSocial + '</td>'
                        + '<td>' + value.NitEmpresa + '</td>'
                        + '<td>' + value.Correo + '</td>'
                        + '<td>' + value.Celular + '</td>'
                        + '<td>' + formatDate(value.licenciaFechaExpire) + '</td>'
                    );
                $('#tblData').append(row);
            });
```

Thank you, I managed to access the brothers 'td', as follows:

```
                    $('tr td:nth-child(3)', '#tblData').click(function () {
```

returns to the father to look for his brothers

```
                            var $thisRow = $(this).closest('tr')
```

brothers td

```
                            IdUsuario = $('td:first', $thisRow).text();
                            RolId = $('td:nth-child(2)', $thisRow).text();
                            Estado= $('td:nth-child(3)', $thisRow).text();
```

//an alert to print the values
                                alert(IdUsuario + '-' + RolId + '-' + Estado);

```
            });
        },
        error: function (jQXHR) {
            toastr.error('Sistemas Infinitos Informa: '+jQXHR.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the meaning of "x3", "x1" and "(x1 of td (x2))"?

Comment: Are you asking how to select the value of a specific td when the tr is clicked?

Comment: If I specify 'click', on a td with id x, the other td of the same row is inaccessible

Comment: @MauricoBello Could you check my answer and tell me if is what you want or if I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: I'm trying to verify

Comment: Estoy tratando de acceder a los hermanos de 'td' donde haces clic en '<td id = "Status">' + value. Estado + '</td>' ...
$ ('# tblBody tr'). on ('click', '#Estado', function ()
{
var cell = $ (this) .text ();
Esto no es accesible:
<tr onclick = "myFunction (this);">

Comment: If you analyze my code, you can see that the table is dynamically loaded, afterload, then click on the 'td' with id = '' Estado', but its brothers' td' are left out

Comment: @MauricoBello By clicking on td with id = "Estado" which values exactly you expect to get?

Comment: example:
the td with id = 'Status', is the td3, ... I need access to the value of td1 and td2, .....
User ID var = $ (this) .find ('td: first'). html ()
var State1 = $ (this) .find ('td: nth-child (2)'). val ();
...

Comment: this is inaccessible
success: function (data) {
scrubber
$ ('# tblBody'). empty ();
$ .each (data, function (index, value) {
row var =
$ ('<tr>'
+ '<td id = "UserID">' + value.User + '</td>'
+ '<td id = "RolId">' + value.RolId + '</td>'
+ '<td id = "Status" onmouseout = "Myfuntion1 (this)">' + value. Status + '</td>'

Comment: '<td id = "Status" onmouseout = "Myfuntion1 (this)">' + value. Status + '</td>' is in a post-caga event

Comment: this works perfect, if it's just a click on a 'tr',
but I need to click on different 'td'
$ ('# tblBody tr'). on ('click', function ()
{....});

Comment: I am trying to do this: success: function (data) { $('#tblBody').empty();  $.each(data, function (index, value) { var row = $('<tr>' +'<td id="td1">'+ value.IdUsuario + '</td>' + '<td id="td2">'   + value.RolId     + '</td>'+ '<td id="td3">' + value.Estado + '</td>' + '<td id="td4">' + value.Rol + '</td>' );  $('#tblData').append(row); }); $('#tblBody tr').on('click', '#td3', function ()  { var celda = $(this).text();//ok  var td1 = $(this).find('td:first').html() //null var td2=$(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').val();//null  alert(celda +'-'+td1+'-'+td2 ); //test returns {ok,null,null}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            var row =
                $('<tr>'
                    +'<td id="IdUsuario">'+ value.IdUsuario + '</td>'
                    + '<td id="RolId">'   + value.RolId     + '</td>'
                    + '<td id="Estado" >' + value.Estado + '</td>'
```

First, each element in the DOM should have a unique id. By repeating the same ID multiple times, I'm not sure your `on('click')` events will attach in all browsers and return the value you are looking for.  Instead, your `click` event should look something like this:

```
 $('tr', '#tblData').click(function () {
     var id1 = $('td:first-child', this).text();
     var id2 = $('td:nth-child(2)', this).text();
     var id3 = $('td:nth-child(3)', this).text();
     ...
 }
```

or if you only want to allow clicking on the first TD:

```
 $('tr td:first-child', '#tblData').click(function () {
     var $thisRow = $(this).closest('tr')
     var id1 = $(this).text();
     var id2 = $('td:nth-child(2)', $thisRow).text();
     var id3 = $('td:nth-child(3)', $thisRow).text();
     ...
 }
```

Comment: One comment to add, I'm not sure if it's less resource intensive for the browser to have a single event handler that is suppressed if not a specific td i.e. `$('#tblData').on('click', 'tr td:first-child', function (){….})` if I had a lot of rows, I might try it both ways to save resources.